# Floating divs, different height, building from left to right. how to fill vertical gaps between levels?

Tags: jquery, css, html

Okay, hello there. Here is the deal.

I have N divs with diffirent heights. I need to build a wall from them. Without extra libraries like masonry or freewall.

My problem is I cant understand how to fill whole wrapper with them correctly. Look at my example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="child">Div 1<br />Something</div>
<div class="child">Div 2<br />Something<br />Something<br />Something<br />Something<br />Something</div> 
<div class="child">Div 3<br />Something<br />Something</div> 
<div class="child">Div 4<br />Something<br />Something<br />Something</div> 
<div class="child">Div 5<br />Something</div> 
<div class="child">Div 6<br />Something<br />Something<br />Something<br />Something<br />Something<br />Something</div> 
<div class="child">Div 7<br />Something<br />Something</div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width:420px;
}
.child {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98Luw/)

There is the problem. Div 4 stacks below Div 3 and not Div 1. It also breaks filling vertically. I cant really find direction to look at. Can anyone help me where to dig? How can I build propper layout with my divs, from left to right, from top to bottom.

Comment: You can't with floats, that's why libraries like masonry and freewall exist.  If it was possible to do it without them, people wouldn't use them.

Comment: Why both `javascript` and `jquery` tags ?

Comment: @f00bar - you're right. My bad.

Comment: @robertc - yes, but they're too 'heavy' for my needs. It's like shooting from bazooka to pigeon. I just need good placement, whithout shuffle, dragging and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded my own script to build a wall with my divs. Kinda solved my problem.

If someone will need this - here is the direction:

check window size, define amount of columns depends on that size, check amounts of divs and build math matrix of them adding classes like row1 col1, row1 col2 etc.

And after that .animation() magic.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have n-divs they've probably are dynamically generated.
In that case try to add an extra class to each first div in a new row:

```
.last{
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/98Luw/17/

I dont know a better approach on this

Cheers

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, but no, this is still leaves the vertical gaps between divs

Answer (score 0):

you can set display: inline-block; instead of floating them:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

although i suggest using a library for this, it may give you a headache on IE

Comment: Thanks. Same as answer from Filip Huysmans, although this is better solution.

Comment: you welcome, if you're going to use "clear" and want it to be responsive i suggest using "nth-child()" for clearance

Answer (score 0):

Gotta admit...learnt a lot from this question....here is [**a solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/98Luw/20/) **using pure css**

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width:420px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.child {
    width:120px;
    padding-left:15px;
    display:inline-table;
}
```

apparently, `display:inline-table;` did the trick!! :)